# Screen Fonts -> Roman Font is Affecting math-mode's Font Suddenly!

Tags: math-mode, fonts, lyx-layouts, roman

everybody.

I changed my LyX default Roman screen font to the David font.

My text looks like this, with David as font for Roman:

[image]

In terms of the font for regular (non-math-mode text), the text has the same font as it had in my LyX before I made any changes to the default fonts.

(for example, if I export the LyX document to PDF), the font change **did not** change the looks - the fonts in PDF looks the same as they looked before the changes I made to the font in LyX.

But, the problem is that David is now affecting the default math-mode font.

In terms of how the fonts looked before I did the changes, non-math-mode text had a David font (or, at least, it looked the way it looks now), and math-mode text had a different font, whose name I don't know (and don't remember well how it looks, either).

Is it possible to somehow revert back to the default fonts, or does anybody know the name of the default math-mode text font, and it's possible to separate non-math-mode and math-mode texts fonts, and apply the 2 different fonts?

Comment: Please clarify: Is the situation afffecting the way the document "looks" on-screen, or is it affecting printed documents?

Comment: It doesn't affect the exported documents.

Thanks for asking. I'll add that information to the post.